# I can't install Ubuntu on my PC AMD (Already tried nomodeset)

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, amd-graphics

As the title states I tried installing Ubuntu on my PC . However, this resulted in a black screen(still trying not installed yet) as soon as I booted and I checked apparently it had something to do with my AMD and not having the drivers and recommended running it with nomodeset which failed and instead I had a splash screen with dialog that flickers through it so it boots but it's un-usable, Please help.

These are my specs:

Case: » SilverStone Kublai KL06

PSU: » SilverStone Strider Essential Bronze 600 W

Motherboard: » ASRock H110M-HDV

CPU: » Intel Core i3-6100

RAM: » Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4-2400 8 GB

GPU» PowerColor Radeon R7 370 PCS+ 2 GB GDDR5

Comment: Are you able to run the live CD/USB?

Comment: it runs but it is unusable ... I get a kind of cuboid multi-colour (what looks like a splash screen or initial wallpaper) but it covers everything and I can see a couple of error dialog boxes flickering.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 16.04 on the live CD/USB? There has been a recent change to the Graphics Drivers for AMD in 16.04: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx so you might want to check if a live USB/CD of Ubuntu 14.04 has the same display issues. (Ubuntu 14.04 is supported for a good few more years, so if it behaves better, you could run 14.04 until the AMD graphic drivers get updated/fixed in 16.04)

Comment: I agree with pHeLiOn, I like to be on the latest and greatest, but I only stay on the slightly bloody edge (kernel 4.6, never the rc's).  I have been fortunate that all my hardware works with 16.04, but if I had issues, I would step back one level and try that.  Maybe when 16.04.1 comes out, your issue will be fixed.  You can always (dare I say, should always, not that I take my own advice) test with live CD/USB before you install.

Comment: I attempted to install 14.04 but same issue , in fact it was worse and wouldnt even reach the splash screen , I gave it around 20 minutes once it reached a pink screen

Comment: Found a link that _might_ help: https://dropline.net/2014/04/ubuntu-and-radeon-video-cards/ (worth noting that it seems to be for 14.04 but you could try with 16.04 first)

Comment: Let us know if it works and, if so, we can put Todd Kulesza's instructions up as an answer in case someone else will find it helpful too.

Comment: I tried the solution with both Ubuntu 16 (reached the same splash screen ) , I managed to get to terminal but it asked me for ubuntu login and password in the live cd , which I have never put so I got stuck there and with ubuntu 14 , I reached a black screen but no cursor and the command did not work and no terminal came up :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work , by disabling CSM in the mobo options and applying nomodeset. It allowed me to get to the Ubuntu install screen without a problem. Installing it as I type this.

Comment: Just small comment for mere mortals like me: CSM=Compatibility Support Module a.k.a. Legacy (BIOS) Mode.